# How not to display the keypressed on device passwords?

Tags: html, css, mobile, passwords

How not to display the keypressed password before it will become bulleted on DEVICE passwords. I need my site not to display first the letters/number when i access it in the (INTERNET TV) mobile, tablet etc.

See the picture.

[image]

i need is when a type a password it will become a bullet form not the exact key that the user pressed. Thanks!

EDIT: I need it to hide in the internet tv where there is no password visiblity functionality.

Comment: you can read [This SE Post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70219/disable-showing-password-input-characters-with-a-physical-keyboard). And for programming, i will try post an answer

Comment: please see the editted question. I need it to hide in the internet tv where there is no password visiblity functionality.

Comment: i dont get it. what is your application? web or native?

Comment: WEB, but the some user access it in their internet t.v for demo purposes. So if they log-in and log-out using the internet tv the password will appears.